# Multibin packing variation: fixed number of unlimited bins, ring buffer array

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I am looking for an optimal algorithm (or at least a good approach) for the following algorithmic problem. (It looks quite close to multibin problem, but has one significant difference.)

**Description:**

We have an array of positive numbers which is a ring buffer. We need to cut it into fixed number of parts, so that the difference between smallest sum of elements and biggest sum of elements among all parts was minimal.

**Example #1:**

```
Array = [7, 16, 11, 3]

Number of parts = 2
```

Optimal partition is:

```
[16] --- [11, 3, 7]
```

because it has minimal difference between smallest sum (16) and biggest sum (11+3+7).

**Example #2:**

```
Array = [7, 16, 3, 11]

Number of parts = 2
```

Optimal partition is:

```
[16, 3] vs [11, 7]
```

because it has minimal difference between smallest sum (16 + 3) and biggest sum (11+7).

***NOTE:*** *Classical multibin problem implies that we can put objects in bins randomly. Here we can put in bins only all objects from contiguous sub-arrays.*